# What algorithm is used by the Scala library method Vector.sorted?

Tags: scala, sorting, vector

I have been looking at the [Scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) but so far I have found no answer to my question, namely what sorting algorithm is used by the method

```
scala.collection.immutable.Vector.sorted
```

The documenation says it is a stable sort, but not the actual algorithm used. Is it a merge sort?

Comment: Why don't you look at the source code?

Comment: I have not thought about it, yes, that's an idea. I suppose it is merge sort, but, while the Java documentation reports the actual algorithm used, e.g. for sorting a collection, the Scala documentation doesn't.

Comment: After going through Java 7 Doc links I have reservation regarding the algorithm that is used. I believe it will be TimSort adaptation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `sorted` method is implemented in `SeqLike`, and seems to use `java.util.Arrays.sort` for its sorting. It builds an array from the vector, then invokes `Arrays.sort` and then converts it back, it seems. According to the [Java 6 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[])), it therefore uses **quicksort**:

> The sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort, adapted from Jon L. Bentley and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function", Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November 1993). This algorithm offers n*log(n) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance.

For Java 7, the algorithm seems to have change (again, citing [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(byte[]))):

> The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.

Scala's `SeqLike#sorted` source [(taken from GitHub)](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/collection/SeqLike.scala#L592):

```
/** Sorts this $coll according to an Ordering.
   *
   *  The sort is stable. That is, elements that are equal (as determined by
   *  `lt`) appear in the same order in the sorted sequence as in the original.
   *
   *  @see [[scala.math.Ordering]]
   *
   *  @param  ord the ordering to be used to compare elements.
   *  @return     a $coll consisting of the elements of this $coll
   *              sorted according to the ordering `ord`.
   */
  def sorted[B >: A](implicit ord: Ordering[B]): Repr = {
    val len = this.length
    val arr = new ArraySeq[A](len)
    var i = 0
    for (x <- this.seq) {
      arr(i) = x
      i += 1
    }
    java.util.Arrays.sort(arr.array, ord.asInstanceOf[Ordering[Object]])
    val b = newBuilder
    b.sizeHint(len)
    for (x <- arr) b += x
    b.result
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1). Merge sort is used by Java on lists (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html). Java 7 uses a modified merge sort.

Comment: Note that in Java 7, `public static void sort(Object[] a)` in class `java.util.Array` uses a variation of merge sort.

Comment: Note that it's `java.util.Arrays`, there's no such thing as `java.util.Array`.

Comment: After going through Java 7 Doc links I have reservation regarding the algorithm that is used. I believe it will be TimSort adaptation.

Comment: Would you care to provide us with a link? :)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: Wrote a sample program to test and debug point Arrays.sort lands in TimSort :) . Screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 10):

I agree broadly with accepted answer. However i would like to add some points w.r.t [**Java 7 Arrays**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[]))

The answer would slightly change w.r.t to changes brought on since **JAVA 7** which uses a variation of QuickSort called `DualPivotQuickSort` to sort **primitive** values in **java.util.Arrays**

JAVA 7 Array Sorting is different for `Primitives` and `Objects`.

### Note from Docs -

**For Primitive value Arrays :**

*The sorting algorithm is a **Dual-Pivot Quicksort** by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations.*

**For Objects Arrays :**

*The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ( **TimSort**). It uses techiques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.*

```
SeqLike.sorted uses 
java.util.Arrays.sort(arr.array, ord.asInstanceOf[Ordering[Object]]) 
where arr.array is instead of ArraySeq.

ArraySeq in Scala stores its data in a plain old Java array, 
but it does not store arrays of primitives; everything is an array of objects. 
This means that primitives get boxed on the way in.
```

### So Java Arrays.sort should be using the **TimSort** !!!!!!

[image]

### Additional Details -

You can find the JAVA7 implementation here - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/Arrays.java

Further Awesome Reading on JAVA 7 - http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.openjdk.core-libs.devel/2628

The changes have impact on scala sorting as being discussed here - http://grokbase.com/t/gg/scala-internals/12ab76zqnk/specializing-ordering-faster-sort