# scala sortBy using insertion sort

Tags: scala

This is a pretty simple question, but how can I get `List.sortBy` to use insertion sort rather than quick sort? I have some data that needs to be continually sorted on itself, so it will always be mostly sorted.

Comment: Does it actually use quicksort? I would expect it to delegate to the JDK's sort, which is probably TimSort (and thus already adaptive).

Comment: You may want to consider just using binary search to maintain sorted order on modifications.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14146990/what-algorithm-is-used-by-the-scala-library-method-vector-sorted, it is in fact, quicksort.

Comment: That answer is pointing to the wrong documentation. It's using the docs for Java's `Arrays.sort(byte[])` instead of `Arrays.<T>sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`. `Arrays.<T>sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)` uses TimSort.

Comment: The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788792/2357112) has things right.

Comment: You can add this custom `sortBy` with the help of type-classes.

Comment: What makes you think that Scala's `List.sortBy` uses quicksort? I couldn't find anything in the Scala Language Specification nor the Scaladocs that specifies *any* particular algorithm for it to use, and I would be really surprised if it did, to be honest. This is something that is best left to the implementation. Not even the C++ specification, which is really precise about such things, specifies the algorithm, it only specifies the maximum number of calls to `operator<` it is allowed to make (O(N log N) for `sort`, for example).

Comment: In Scala-JVM, for example, `sortBy` is currently implemented by simply calling `sorted`. The documentation for `sorted` specifies that `sorted` is stable. Since QuickSort is *unstable*, this means that `sorted` *cannot possibly* use QuickSort. (Although, of course, since the documentation for `sortBy` *does not* state that it is stable, it is perfectly possible and legal for the implementation to be changed to QuickSort. But at the moment, that is not the case, but it has been true for at least the last 7 years.)

Comment: On Scala-JVM, `sorted` in turn calls `java.util.Arrays.sort`, which is guaranteed to be stable. On Scala.js and Scala-native, interestingly, `sorted` *also* calls `java.util.Arrays.sort`, even though the JRE standard library doesn't even exist in those two implementations; they actually *re-implement* parts of the JRE in Scala. Scala.js implements `java.util.Arrays.sort` using a stable insertion sort, but Scala-native interestingly implements it using QuickSort (with a switch to merge sort for very small partitions). Oracle JDK's implementation uses TimSort, but AFAIK J9's does not.